# Проблема с добавлением потоков в программу.Java

Tags: java, gui, графика, j2ee

Есть программа , и нужно добавить поток (BaseAI) ,который будет работать с объектами. Рисование должно остаться в главном потоке . Синхронизировать роботу потоков с рисованием (через передачу данных в основной поток). Пробовал сделать основную функцию в потоке,но у меня всегда были проблемы с передачей данных в основной поток.
Очень прошу,помогите пожалуйста разобраться (может есть пример какой то, либо знаете сайт который сможет помочь) 
Я только начал работать с потоками поэтому не судите строго.

Код:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class  LabSixFirst extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame wnd;
    private float w, q, p;
    private int t0, t;
    private Timer timer;
    private JButton start, stop, apply;
    private JLabel ql, wl;
    private JTextField qtf, wtf;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LabSixFirst();
    }

    LabSixFirst() {
        w = 5;
        q = 50;
        t0 = 1000/60;
        timer = new Timer(t0, this);
        timer.setActionCommand("timer");
        wnd = new JFrame("Lab-6.1");
        wnd.setLayout(null);
        wnd.setSize(500, 500);
        wnd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 50, 300, 300);
        start = new JButton("Start");
        stop = new JButton("Stop");
        apply = new JButton("Apply");
        ql = new JLabel("q");
        wl = new JLabel("w");
        qtf = new JTextField(q + "");
        wtf = new JTextField(w + "");
        ql.setBounds(5, 380, 20, 20);
        wl.setBounds(5, 400, 20, 20);
        qtf.setBounds(30, 380, 40, 20);
        wtf.setBounds(30, 400, 40, 20);
        start.setActionCommand("start");
        stop.setActionCommand("stop");
        apply.setActionCommand("apply");
        start.addActionListener(this);
        stop.addActionListener(this);
        apply.addActionListener(this);
        start.setBounds(300, 430, 80, 20);
        stop.setBounds(390, 430, 80, 20);
        apply.setBounds(5, 430, 80, 20);
        wnd.add(this);
        wnd.add(start);
        wnd.add(stop);
        wnd.add(apply);
        wnd.add(ql);
        wnd.add(wl);
        wnd.add(qtf);
        wnd.add(wtf);
        wnd.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Random ra= new Random();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawLine(getWidth()/2 - (int)(q/2.0f), getHeight()/2, getWidth()/2 + (int)(q/2.0f), getHeight()/2);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillOval(getWidth()/2 - (int)(q/2.0f + 3) + (int)p, getHeight()/2 -3, 6, 6);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
            case "stop" : {
                timer.stop();
                break;
            }
            case "start" : {
                timer.start();
                break;
            }
            case "apply" : {
                float a, b;
                try {
                    a = Float.parseFloat(qtf.getText());
                    b = Float.parseFloat(wtf.getText());
                    q = a;
                    w = b;
                    repaint();
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                break;
            }
            case "timer" : {
                p = q * (float)(1.0f + Math.cos(w * t /1000 - Math.PI)) / 2.0f;
                repaint();
                t+=t0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Один из примеров того что я пробовал:

```
static class oThread extends Thread implements ActionListener{

        public void run(){
            t0 = 1000/60;
            timer = new Timer(t0, this);
            timer.setActionCommand("timer");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            switch (actionEvent.getActionCommand()) {
                case "timer":
                {
                    p = q * (float) (1.0f + Math.cos(w * t / 1000 - Math.PI)) / 2.0f;
                    repaint();
                    t += t0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Может для начала вам про100 начать с потоков без рисования и усложнений если вам такое не много сложно? Программирование это всегда конструктивный подход. Декомпозиция задачи и конструктивное решение (от простого к сложному). Заставьте для начала работать 2 потока, а затем усложняйте.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам конкретно про Swing, то вам нужен [javax.swing.SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). В Интернете можно найти много примеров использования, да и в любом пособии по Swing обязательно должно быть.
Если же вы просто хотите разобраться с многопоточностю, что начинать со Swing неудачная идея.

Comment: К сожалению нас не спрашивали. Нам задали задание сделать потоки с Swing-ом. Хоть мы только и начали их учить. Ни примеры не дали,ни лекции. Сказали что такое потоки и все. Поэтому ищу помощи тут(